# socket [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] (_ssl.c:590) from Client.py to Node Server.js

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, sockets, ssl

I am getting this error

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 844, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 835, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

I am trying to establish a secure connection(ssl.socket) between a python client and a node.js server and I took the above  error. I don't know what is missing or what's my fault. Here is my source code both for python client and for node.js server

Server Socket in Node.js :

```
var _HOST = '192.168.1.136';
    var _PORT = 1337;
    var _address;

    const tls = require('tls');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const options = {
        // These are necessary only if using the client certificate authentication
        key: fs.readFileSync('./SSL_TLS/ServerCakey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./SSL_TLS/Server-cert.pem'),
        requestCert: true
    };

    var server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
        //const ProtocolEmmitter = new BasicProtocolEmmitter();

        socket.on('connect', (e) => {
            console.log('client connected ' +
                socket.remoteAddress + ':' +
                socket.remotePort);
            console.log('server connected',
                socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
        });

        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('clients says' + ': ' + data);
        });

        socket.on('error', function(data) {
            console.log('client on error', data);

        });

        socket.on('close', (e) => {
            console.log('client disconnected');
            socket.end;
            setTimeout(() => {
                server.close();
                server.listen(_PORT, _HOST, () => {
                    _address = server.address();
                    console.log('opened server on %j', _address);
                    console.log(' Server listening on %j ', _HOST, ':', _PORT);
                });
            }, 10000);
        });

    });
```

and here is my Client.py Socket :(I am using  Python 2.7.11)

```
class SSLSocket:
    def __init__(self):
        Context = self.__loadContext()
        self._SSL_Sock = Context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
                                                           server_hostname=host)
       self._SSL_Sock.connect((host, port))

    def __loadContext(self):
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
        context.check_hostname = True
        context.load_verify_locations("..Path/Client.crt")
        return context
```

i forgot to mention that i create with success the client.crt and i validate it with success

```
 `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out client.crt` 

Signature Ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     context.load_verify_locations("..Path/Client.crt")
> ```

I think you have to problems here:

- Wrong setup of the trust path: `load_verify_locations` should setup the trusted CA, i.e. it should contain the issuer of the servers certificate and not some client certificate.
- Missing setup of the client certificate: For loading the client certificates you should use [load_cert_chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain).